# Different behaviour of Classroom API in function if called individually or from a loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

This is a complex and strange issue I'm facing and I hope anyone could bring me, if not a solution to the problem, something to circumvent it.
Starting from the beginning, I'm the administrator in a school that uses Google Suite for Education and Classroom for managing coursework with students, specially now that we are forced to work from home.

We think it should be a good idea to use Classroom API to get a good view of the students work and their grading as a whole. So we made a Spreadsheet and a script to get a report that shows all coursework from a student with his gradings in all the subjects (courses in Classroom) he is attending. So far, after solving some misunderstandings of the API, we managed to code the script.

After this we tried to upsize the script so that we could make a report for one group of students in one time, which is a great advance since making 30 reports individually is time-consuming. That wasn't very difficult, since we have all the list of students and groups in a sheet and more or less it is done with a loop. And it worked and we can get a full report of all students in a group, for all their coursework in all the subjects.

But the problem came when we started to run this script and we are getting errors in some groups, in some students, and we do not know why. After some investigation, we found that the call to *Classroom.Courses.list(optionalArgs)* gives 430 courses, although we are using a filter for the student in the report. 430 courses is not a high number but the loop for all of them, even considering that the student is not enrolled in them, takes longer than 1800 s and the script rises an 'out of time error'.

Surprisingly, if I run the same function called inside the loop for the group but in a direct call, then it works flawlessly and gives me no error. In this case, the student that gives the previous error is not enrolled in any course so the call to *Classroom.Courses.list(optionalArgs)* gives me a null set of courses and the function returns almost instantly without making any report.

I am showing the full script code, but the interesting part of it is not so long. It has many parts that do supporting tasks such as getting data form other sheets or showing Html dialogs on screen.

Best regards
Rafael

P.S. Excuse me for this long text, but the code is much longer and I think explaining the situation can improve understanding our problem.

```
    // Menu
    function onOpen() {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.createMenu('Functions')
          .addItem('Group report','fReportGroupHtml')
          .addItem('Student report','fStudentReportHtml')
          .addToUi();
    }

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Report for 1 student
//  Opens HTML dialog to select group and student
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
function fStudentReportHtml()
{
  // Html dialog
  try {
    var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('SelecStudent');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(output,'Select student');
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    return;
  }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Report for 1 student
//  Receives information from dialog and makes report
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
function fStudentReport(form_data)
{
  // Form information
  var nameStudent=form_data.student;

  // Split students name and surname
  var posco=nameStudent.indexOf(',');
  var surname=nameStudent.substring(0,posco);
  var name=nameStudent.substring(posco+2);

  // Gets student email
  var idStudent=getUserEmail(name,surname);

  // List student coursework
  var ssCourses=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var hWorks=ssCourses.getSheetByName("StWork");
  fListStudentWork(idStudent,hWorks,nameStudent);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Report for all students in a group
//  Opens HTML dialog to select group
function fReportGroupHtml()
{
  // Html dialog
  try {
    var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('SelecGroup');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(output,'Select group');
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    return;
  }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Report for all students in a group
//  Receives information from dialog and makes report
function fReportGroup(form_data)
{
  var idStudents="1wvjqUFZcRwjTKSspjyQOE1JHio33f7seyx8xCO8qHBQ";
  var idTemplateInf="1K6YgZvh195eo4b-DLtRHuvjFdG3SOBJILodzS4CUnBs";
  var idCarpInf="16nH3BhAwHPP3BcAUK9eW_FQdWRM6B87T";
  var valAlu=[[]];

  // Opens students sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idStudents);
  var coursesSS = ss.getSheetByName("Students");
  var lastrow=coursesSS.getLastRow();
  var rangeA=coursesSS.getRange(2,2,lastrow-1,3).getValues();

  // First student in the group
  for(var ii=0; ii<lastrow-1; ii++)
  {
    if (rangeA[ii][2]==form_data.groupAlu)
      break;
  }
  var ini=ii;

  // Opens sheet for messaging
  var ssClass = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // Copies template sheet into a new file
  var idNewFileInf = DriveApp.getFileById(idTemplateInf).makeCopy(idCarpInf).getId();
  DriveApp.getFileById(idNewFileInf).setName('Report '+form_data.groupAlu);

  // Opens new sheet and writes general information
  var ssInf = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idNewFileInf);
  var hjInfAlu = ssInf.getSheetByName("Students");
  hjInfAlu.getRange(2,1).setValue("GRUPO: "+form_data.groupAlu);
  var dateToday=new Date();
  hjInfAlu.getRange(3,1).setValue("FECHA: "+Utilities.formatDate(dateToday,"GMT+1","dd/MM/yyyy"));

  // All students in the group
  var iiAlu=1;
  while(rangeA[ii][2]==form_data.groupAlu)
  {
    // Gets student's information
    var surname=rangeA[ii][0];
    var name=rangeA[ii][1];
    var nameStudent=surname+", "+name;

    // Gets student email
    var idStudent=getUserEmail(name,surname);

    // Copies sheet
    var hjInfWork = ssInf.getSheetByName("Works").copyTo(ssInf).setName(nameStudent);

    // Makes report of student's work and submissions
    var mens="Creando informe de student: "+nameStudent;
    ssClass.toast(mens, "Informe de tareas",-1);
    var states=fListStudentWork(idStudent,hjInfWork,nameStudent);

    // Writes student information in first sheet
    valAlu[0][0]=iiAlu;
    valAlu[0][1]=nameStudent;
    valAlu[0][2]=states[0];
    valAlu[0][3]=states[1];
    valAlu[0][4]=states[2];
    hjInfAlu.getRange(iiAlu+5, 1, 1, 5).setValues(valAlu);
    ii++;
    iiAlu++;
  }

  // Deletes sheet 'Works'
  ssInf.deleteSheet(ssInf.getSheetByName("Works"));

  // Final message
  ssClass.toast("Fin del informe", "Informe de tareas",5);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// List coursework for a student
function fListStudentWork(idStudent, dataSheet, nameStudent)
{
  // Variables
  var ii=0;
  var lWorks=[[]];
  var stateWork=[0,0,0];
  var pageToken = null;
  var pageToken2 = null;
  var colorCourse1= "#ddffdd";
  var colorCourse2= "#f9e9b0";
  var iiColor=0;
  var optionalArgs=
  {
    pageToken: pageToken,
    courseStates: 'ACTIVE',
    studentId: idStudent,
    pageSize: 0
  };
  var optionalArgs2=
  {
    userId: idStudent,
    pageSize: 0
  };

  // Date today
  var now = new Date();
  var year=now.getFullYear();
  var month=now.getMonth();

  // Date starting term
  if (month>=8) 
    var cadfecha="September 1, "+year.toString();
  else
    var cadfecha="September 1, "+(year-1).toString();  
  var fechaini=new Date(cadfecha);

  // Empty sheet
  var rowWorks=dataSheet.getLastRow();
  var colWorks=dataSheet.getLastColumn();
  if (rowWorks>3)
  {
    var rnWorks=dataSheet.getRange(4, 1, rowWorks-3, colWorks);
    rnWorks.clearContent().clearFormat();
  }

  // General information in sheet
  if (!nameStudent)
    nameStudent=getUserName(idStudent);
  Logger.log("INI: "+nameStudent);
  dataSheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue("ENTREGAS DEL ALUMNO: "+nameStudent);
  var dateToday=new Date();
  dataSheet.getRange(2, 1).setValue("FECHA: "+Utilities.formatDate(dateToday,"GMT+1","dd/MM/yyyy"));

  // First: courses for the student
  var response = Classroom.Courses.list(optionalArgs);
  var courses = response.courses;
  if (!courses || courses.length === 0)
    dataSheet.getRange(4, 2).setValue("No hay clases");
  else 
  {
    Logger.log(" courses: "+courses.length);
    for (course in courses)
    {
      var fechaCourse=new Date(courses[course].creationTime);

      if (fechaCourse>=fechaini)
      {
        // Information from the course
        var idCourse=courses[course].id;
        var nomprof=getUserName(courses[course].ownerId);
        var colorCourse=(iiColor==0)? colorCourse1 : colorCourse2;
        iiColor=1-iiColor;

        // Gets coursework from the course
        var responseT = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(idCourse);
        var works = responseT.courseWork;
        if (!works || works.length === 0)
          dataSheet.getRange(4, 2).setValue("No hay información");
        else 
        {
          for (work in works)
          {
            var idWork=works[work].id;
            var maxPoints=(works[work].maxPoints==null)? "" : works[work].maxPoints;

            // Gets submissions
            try
            {
              var responseE = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.list(idCourse, idWork, optionalArgs2);
              var submis = responseE.studentSubmissions;
            }
            catch(ee)
            {
              var submis=null;
            }
            if (submis && submis.length >0)
            {
              for (subm in submis)
              {
                lWorks[0][0]=ii+1;
                lWorks[0][1]=courses[course].name;
                lWorks[0][2]=nomprof;
                lWorks[0][3]=works[work].title;
                var dateWork=works[work].dueDate;
                if (dateWork==null)
                  lWorks[0][4]="--/--/----";
                else 
                  lWorks[0][4]=dateWork.day+"/"+dateWork.month+"/"+dateWork.year;
                var points=(submis[subm].assignedGrade==null)? "" : submis[subm].assignedGrade; 
                lWorks[0][5]=points+" / "+maxPoints;
                var dateSubmis=submis[entrega].creationTime;
                if (dateSubmis==null)
                  lWorks[0][6]="--/--/----";
                else lWorks[0][6]=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dateSubmis), "GMT+1","dd/MM/yyyy");
                var state=submis[subm].state;

                // Gets state of submission
                var cState="";
                var lateSubmis=0;
                if ((state=="RETURNED")||(state=="TURNED_IN"))
                {
                  cState="ENTREGADO";
                  stateWork[0]++;
                }
                else
                {
                  // Checks if late or not handed
                  if (dateWork!=null)
                  {
                    var dateEnd=new Date(dateWork.year,dateWork.month-1,dateWork.day);
                    if (dateEnd.valueOf()<dateToday.valueOf())
                    {
                      cState="NO ENTREGADO";
                      stateWork[1]++;
                      lateSubmis=1;
                    }
                    else
                      stateWork[2]++;
                  }
                }

                lWorks[0][7]=cState;              
                dataSheet.getRange(ii+4, 1, 1, 8).setValues(lWorks).setBackground(colorCourse);
                if (lateSubmis)
                  dataSheet.getRange(ii+4, 8).setFontColor("red").setFontWeight("bold");
                else
                  dataSheet.getRange(ii+4, 8).setFontColor("black").setFontWeight("normal");
                ii++;
              }
            }
          }  
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return(stateWork);
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Gets list of groups
function listGroups()
{
  var idStudents="1wvjqUFZcRwjTKSspjyQOE1JHio33f7seyx8xCO8qHBQ";

  try 
  {
    // Opens students sheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idStudents);
    var coursesSS = ss.getSheetByName("Students");
    var lastrow=coursesSS.getLastRow();
    var rangeA=coursesSS.getRange(2,4,lastrow-1,1).getValues();
    var courses = [];
    var courseant="";
    for(var ii=0; ii<lastrow-1; ii++) 
    {
      if (rangeA[ii][0]!=courseant)
      {
        courseant=rangeA[ii][0];
        courses.push(courseant);
      }
    }

    return courses;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Gets list of students in group
function listStudents(group) 
{
  var idStudents="1wvjqUFZcRwjTKSspjyQOE1JHio33f7seyx8xCO8qHBQ";

  try 
  {
    // Opens students sheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idStudents);
    var coursesSS = ss.getSheetByName("Students");
    var lastrow=coursesSS.getLastRow();
    var rangeA=coursesSS.getRange(2,1,lastrow-1,4).getValues();

    // First student
    for(var ii=0; ii<lastrow-1; ii++) 
    {
      if (rangeA[ii][3]==group)
        break;
    }
    var ini=ii;

    // Last student
    while(rangeA[ii][3]==group)
      ii++;

    // Gets array of students
    var students=coursesSS.getRange(2+ini,2,ii-ini,2).getValues();
    return students;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Gets list of courses
function listCourses()
{
  try 
  {
    // Opens courses sheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var coursesSS = ss.getSheetByName("Courses");
    var lastrow=coursesSS.getLastRow();
    var courses=coursesSS.getRange(3,2,lastrow-2,4).getValues();
    return courses;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Gets user name from ID
function getUserName(usid)
{
  var result = AdminDirectory.Users.get(usid, {fields:'name'});
  var fullname = result.name.fullName;
  return fullname;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Gets user email from name
function getUserEmail(name,surname)
{
  var userIds = AdminDirectory.Users.list({domain:"iesciudadjardin.com",
                                           query:"givenName:'"+name+"' familyName:'"+surname+"'"}).users;
  if ((userIds==undefined)||(userIds.length!=1))
    return null;
  else
    return userIds[0].primaryEmail;
}
```

---

Aditional information

I understand the question is too big, so I am going to try explaining things with as little code as possible.
Essentialy my code works. It hangs sometimes with some students. The main part of it is the function *fListStudentWork*:

```
// List coursework for a student
function fListStudentWork(idStudent, dataSheet, nameStudent)
{
  var optionalArgs=
  {
    pageToken: pageToken,
    courseStates: 'ACTIVE',
    studentId: idStudent,
    pageSize: 0
  };

  // First: courses for the student
  var response = Classroom.Courses.list(optionalArgs);
  var courses = response.courses;
  if (!courses || courses.length === 0)
    // NO COURSES
  else 
  {
   // MAKE REPORT
  }
}
```

And now, if I call it with one special student, it works, returning a null set of courses, since John Smith is not enrolled in any course (it also happens with students enrolled in some courses):

```
function OneStudentReport()
{
  fListStudentWork("john.smith@mydomain.com",mySheet,"John Smith");
}
```

But if I loop with a set of students, in which John Smith is part, all the previous students reports are Ok, and when the loop reaches him, it returns all the courses in my school, and the script aborts with a time out error.

```
function fReportGroup(form_data)
{
  // All students in the group
  while(StudentGroup=="MYGROUP")
  {
    // Gets student's information
    var surname=rangeA[ii][0];
    var name=rangeA[ii][1];
    var nameStudent=surname+", "+name;

    // Gets student email
    var idStudent=getUserEmail(name,surname);

    // Makes report of student's work and submissions
    var states=fListStudentWork(idStudent,MySheet,nameStudent);
  }
}
```

P.S. If the administrator thinks I should delete the first part of the message with the full code because it is too long, let me know.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)........Read about the minimum reproducible example.....We don't want to debug your whole script....That's your problem.

Comment: As of right now are you getting any error or it is just a timeout for that much amount of time you are spending?
Could you log the input and ensure that the variables are the same at `fListStudentWork`? The behavior you are describing is very weird so my first guess is that when you are looping thorugh all the students you may be passing wrong values to your function, please confirm that.

Answer (score 1):

and sorry for my late answer. I have been thoroughly testing my code and I think I found the source of the error. The function fListStudentWork receives an id of the student to list his work. This id can be his email. If I called it directly, I used his email directly, so no errors were given. However, when I used it in the loop for all the group, I recalled his id from his name and surname, and here I found some errors: in a couple of sudents with the same familyName and very similar givenName, which is the way I use to get his email, using Directory API.
In these few cases, the email returned was null, and function fListStudentWork did not check for a null email. In addition, inside the function, Classroom API returned me all the 400 courses when I requested assignments for the null student, which finally led my script to time out, unable to handle such number of courses. Now the question could be why the Directory API returns null for such users, but I will write it in another question. 
Thank you all for your help.